# PDO - 'no fields' result when AzureSQL is returning a result

Tags: php, azure, pdo

I'm using PDO::query to run the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO pages (template_id,user_id,page_default,page_internal_title,page_menu_text,page_nav_link,globalcontent_id,page_parent_id,page_order,page_active,page_show_in_menu,page_hide,page_created,page_updated,page_deleted,page_type) values (
4,1,'n','Test',
...snip...
'n','page');SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID=@@IDENTITY
```

Which if I run in the AzureSQL manager directly performs the insert as expected and returns the last_insert_id as it should.

However, when I call `fetchAll()` on the statement object returned from PDO::query, it throws an "The active result for the query contains no fields." exception. PDO::query is working, as the row is being inserted, but it's as though either the select is failing (but it's not throwing an exception at that point), or there is something obvious I'm missing (more than likely).

Any help would be great!

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried a prepared statement? This way you get rid of you SQL injection vulnerability and it might work...

Comment: Believe me I wish I could - the problem is I'm having to fudge this into a very old wrapper - it's a legacy codebase that is now required to run on Azure - the original wrapper still used mysql_* (sigh), but it's too extensive to re-write the wrapper methods.

Thanks for the suggestion though Zombie, I know that's the right way to do it.

Comment: Well, unfortunately we all have to work with legacy code from time to time. I'm pretty sure I read about PDO with MSSQL not supporting multiple result sets, but I can't find the reference at the moment :-/ Have you tried [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)?

Comment: D'Oh - why did I not think to try that?! Yes, that works - put it down as an answer and I'll award it to you! :-) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)?

I'm pretty sure I read about PDO with MSSQL not supporting multiple result sets, but I can't find the reference at the moment :-/. If your scenario allows you to use the function above, this might be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help...now to go kludge everything else into shape... :-|